# Can Domain Access ensure that a civi 'admin' on domain-B can not login via domain-C and see contacts they should not see?

Tags: drupal, multisite, drupal-multi-site

My recollection maybe wrong on this. Scenario is

- main site A
- subsite B
- subsite C

Subsites B and C are created via Domain Access module and are correctly wired in to civicrm so that a contact created on siteB is added to GroupB and hence the subsite-admin on site B can log in to Civi but only see contacts in Group B.

Excellent.

What I am missing is how to ensure via Roles and Permissions (or something extra) that subsite-admin B cannot login in via subsite C (which they currently can and hence can see contacts in Group C)

I have looked at domain_roles and domain_login but neither give me what I expect.

Look forward to having the obvious missing link pointed out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is possible in a fairly blunt way by using the domain_bonus_login_restrict module which is part of the [Domain Bonus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_bonus)